# How Ckan-oauth2 extension works?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, ckan

I have been researching on oauth2 extension of ckan, from below url's :

https://github.com/conwetlab/ckanext-oauth2

https://github.com/etalab/ckanext-oauth2

i have installed the extension and added the configurations to development.ini. I have setup the oauth server too..

but i'm not sure how this extenstion actually works ?

can anyone please suggest me some documentions for this...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my Ckan-Oauth2 extension working atlast.. 
How this extension Works or what changes after adding this extension are :

- Authentication is done by Oauth Server instead of Ckan basic authentication.
- Accessing API's can be done by Access Token generated by Oauth Server instead of static API-KEY.

I couldn't find any documentation for this but i have tested these.. :)

Hope it helps

Comment: It now has a wiki page with a nice explanation of how it works: https://github.com/conwetlab/ckanext-oauth2/wiki